# Paid app to free app distribution

Tags: iphone

I had a paid app on app store (e.g Old 1.1) and i am going to upload one more app (e.g New 2.0) not a upgrade and i want this app to be given to my old customers as free who had paid for app(Old 1.1).
Please suggest how can i achieve the above case.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't doing it as an update to the old application?

Comment: @Alastair Pitts    He's right this should be just added as an upgrade... I mean if you want people who have already paid to get it for free, and new customers to pay... that is exactly what the update option is designed to do. However, if you have some reason why it would be better not to do this I'm very interested to know what it is

Answer (score 4):

make a new 2nd app and update the old 1.1 (with a new option 'get promotion key' for your new 2.0 app).

Comment: This is the alternative, as long as he doesn't have over 50 people who have already purchased his app